# How to track sells you make by visitors referred by another website?

Tags: php, statistics, tracking, visitors

In my future website, I'll have partners and I want them to receive a certain percentage of money according to how much the visitors they sent me bought items.

So this is a simple question:

**How to know where the visitor comes from when he decide to purchase a thing on my website so I give the correct amount to the partner who referred the member?**

(i use the php Symfony framework, I guess it has nothing to do with, but anyhow... ;D )

Comment: There are usually tokens/identifiers associated with uris that track down where they user came from, something like affliate marketing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, this involves giving each partner some kind of unique ID, and then having them include that ID as a variable in the initial page they link to on your site. You then keep track of this ID in a session (either PHP's built-in sessions, or a cookie), and associate it with any purchases made. You can then go aggregate purchases by the associated partner ID to know who to give a cut.

For instance, a partner might link to your site like this:

```
http://www.your-example-site.com/some-product-page?referrer=QK117A4
```

where `QK117A4` is their unique ID.

Comment: and after in my header :

if ($_GET['referrer']) {
setcookie.......
}

and in the page where the user are about to pay 

if isset cookie(referrer)
$sql = update sells set parteners = parteners+1 where idParteners=...

That code is just awefull it's just for you to validate the logical part. Is that right ?

Comment: That's one way to do it - but I'd highly suggest instead of just incrementing a value in a table, mark each *order* record with the partner id, and then when you need the counts, run a query like `SELECT COUNT(partnerid) FROM orders GROUP BY partnerid`. That way, you keep a record of the actual sales that each partnerid generated - it's a lot easier to go back and verify that the numbers are correct later if something seems fishy.